# Access tuple (defined by libc) using an index

Tags: swift, posix, cinterop

I understand that Swift tuples cannot be indexed at runtime. However, I'm working with the POSIX terminal interface (defined by `<termios.h>`, which is part of libc).

In the C code, we are able to modify the state of the terminal by doing stuff like this:

```c
termios_struct.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
termios_struct.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
```

Translating that to Swift raises an error, complaining that it `cannot access element using subscript for tuple type '(cc_t, cc_t, cc_t ...)' (aka '(UInt8, UInt8, UInt8 ...)')`. The actual tuples have about twenty elements, all `UInt8`.

I guess I could just print the values of `VMIN` and `VTIME` (constants defined by `<termios.h>`), then use their values to directly index the tuples, but I'm not sure their values are consistent across platforms, and it's just generally hacky.

What's the proper way to handle this situation?

---

Edit: This issue is addressed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32002556/21916482) to another question, named [Using `termios` in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31465943/using-termios-in-swift?rq=2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [answer you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32002556/21916482) as a guide, I came up with the following extension that seems to work.

```swift
extension termios {
    subscript(c_cc index: Int32) -> cc_t {
        get {
            var settings = self
            var res: cc_t = 0
            withUnsafePointer(to: &settings.c_cc) { (tuplePtr) -> Void in
                tuplePtr.withMemoryRebound(to: cc_t.self, capacity: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: self.c_cc)) {
                    res = $0[Int(index)]
                }
            }

            return res
        }
        set {
            var settings = self
            withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &self.c_cc) { (tuplePtr) -> Void in
                tuplePtr.withMemoryRebound(to: cc_t.self, capacity: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: settings.c_cc)) {
                    $0[Int(index)] = newValue
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's some sample code:

```
var settings = termios()
print(settings.c_cc)
settings[c_cc: VMIN] = 1
print(settings.c_cc)
print(settings[c_cc: VMIN])
```

which outputs:

> (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
> (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)
> 1

Answer (score 1):

Since `c_cc` is an array of bytes, e.g. `[UInt8]`, you can do following

```
var tty = termios()

withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &tty.c_cc)
{
    c_cc in
    c_cc[size_t(VMIN)]  = 1
    c_cc[size_t(VTIME)] = 0
}
```